# Add a replcement billing email if empty for credit card paymen in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, orders, payment-method

In WooCommerce, we have 2 payments methods, cash on delivery and credit card online.

I have the following problem in Checkout page:
The payment processor requires the email address from the customer, and it's mandatory. 
Then we have made the billing email field mandatory. But that makes a big drop in the conversion rate.

So what I would like for the "email" field is: 
If the customer doesn't enter his email address, then we should autopopulate the field or the data sent to the payment processor with a generic replacement email like "contact@domain.com".

And if the customer enters his email address, then everything will go through.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, **there is a much more effective way**: When the order is placed, on order creation, just before the payment, if the billing email is empty and the selected payment method is not COD, we set a temporary generated email address replacement as billing email. 
Then, just after the payment, we remove this email replacement.

This temporary email replacement is generated from the customer complete name *(or if there is no name, we generate an alphabetical random string)* and from a domain name defined in the first function. This way, the payment gateway can't detect that the email is a fake.

The code:

```php
// Utility function that generates an email from customer name
function generate_email_from_name( $order ) {
    $email_domain = 'gmail.com'; // <== HERE set the email domain name

    $email_name   = sanitize_title( $order->get_billing_first_name() );
    $email_name  .= sanitize_title( $order->get_billing_last_name() );
    $email_name   = substr( str_replace( '-', '', $email_name ), 0, 16 );
    
    if ( empty($email_name) ) {
        // Generate an alphabetic string if name is empty
        $email_name = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 14)), 0, 14);
    }
    return sanitize_email($email_name.'@'.$email_domain);
}

// Add a replacement email to the order, just before the payment
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'auto_fill_empty_billing_email' );
function auto_fill_empty_billing_email( $order) {
    // If email is empty and if the payment method is not COD
    if( ! $order->get_billing_email() && $order->get_payment_method() !== 'cod' ) {
        // The generated billing email replacement
        $replacement_email = generate_email_from_name( $order );
        // Set the replacement billing email
        $order->set_billing_email( $replacement_email );
        $order->update_meta_data('replacement_email', 'YES' ); // Tag the order
    }
}

// Remove the replacement email just after the payment
add_action( 'woocommerce_pre_payment_complete', 'remove_replacement_email'  );
function remove_replacement_email( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // If there is a replacement email, we remove it
    if( $order->get_meta('replacement_email') ) {
        $order->set_billing_email('');
        $order->delete_meta_data('replacement_email');
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

---

If needed, here is the code to make the billing email field optional:

```php
// Make billing email optional
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'optional_billing_email_field', 20, 2 );
function optional_billing_email_field($fields){
    $fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
```